# Classes and Queue's

Tags: c++, class, queue

I am trying to figure out how to work with Queues and Classes.

How can i insert information into this class with a queue?

I created the queue `queue<Processes> PrinterDevices`

How do i go about insert stuff on this queue into a class or reading from it?

```
class Processes
{
    public:
        void setPID (int a)
        {
            PID = a;
        }
        int retrievePID()
        {
            return PID;
        }
        void setFilename (string input)
        {
            Filename = input;
        }
        string retrieveFilename()
        {
            return Filename;
        }
        void setMemstart (int a)
        {
            Memstart = a;
        }
        int retrieveMemstart()
        {
            return Memstart;
        }
        void setRW (char a)
        {
            rw = a;
        }
        int retrieveRW()
        {
            return rw;
        }
        void setFilelength (string input)
        {
            Filelength = input;
        }
        string retrieveFilelength()
        {
            return Filelength;
        }
    private:
        int PID;
        string Filename;
        int Memstart;
        char rw;
        string Filelength;
};
```

Comment: question not clear.. please expalin elaborately...

Comment: Basically i want to insert the variables PID/Filename/MemStart/RW/File length into a queue, and print them. How do i do this with a class?

Comment: Iterating over a queue is not possible because it provides a minimal interface. See the below link for the complete description.

"How to iterate over a priority_queue?"

So I would prescribe you to provide stl:: deques which will help your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queue<Processes> PrinterDevices;
Processess obj;
//Populate object through setter methods
```

To add this object to `queue PrinterDevices`

```
`PrinterDevices.push(obj);`
```

Similarly you can create more object..
To traverse...

```
while(!PrinterDevices.empty())
{
      Processes obj = PrinterDevices.front();
         //Add code to use obj;
      PrinterDevices.pop();//Remove the object from queue which is already used above
}
```

Comment: I create a copy of my queue when i print it. But i need to use queue for my assignment.

Comment: So if you don't want to retain the objects you are storing 'front()' and `pop()` can be used to traverse the list...Look for the changes once I have edited the code above

Comment: got it. Now how do i add to certain things such as setpid or or setfilename in my class?

Comment: `obj.setFilename ("filename.txt");` and call other setter methods...finally call `PrinterDevices.push(obj)` to add object to queue...

Comment: HadeS How would i print that object after i added it into the queue?